# About google-map-api quota in local dev environment？

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I run a piece of code that inquire some geography data by google map api, in my local dev environment. The return result is following:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

I want to know if quota constraints are equally effective in the development environment?

And, How to see my quota situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every API has its quota limits and your application will be governed by that. It does not matter if it is a local env. or if your application is hosted on an App Engine instance. The calls are still going from your application account, hence it should count towards the quota.

To view the current usage of the available quote of any of the Google APIs enabled for your project, you can refer to the [Google Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). Go to the project and click on any of the APIs enabled for your project. You should be able to see the current quota used.

For Google Maps API V3 , you have the following free quota:
1.0 requests/second/user  & 25,000 requests/day

So, beyond that you will not be permitted and might have to

Answer (score 0):

You can see your quota [google apis console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)